# XSLT: Transforming HTML attributes into inline CSS

Tags: html, css, xslt

I have invalid HTML that I am trying to transform into valid HTML using an XSLT transformation.  For example, I want to turn some attributes into inline CSS.  Consider the following:

```
    <table border="1" id="t01" width="100%">    
        .
        .
        .                               
    </table>
```

The `border` and `width` attributes on the `table` element are obsolete. So I want to use inline CSS instead, like this:

```
    <table style="border:1;width:100%;" id="t01">   
        .
        .
        .                               
    </table>
```

How can I do this with XSLT?

Comment: Note: border attribute is obsolete too and there are no CSS properties called rules or cellpadding (there is border and border-collapse though).

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: God, I hate it when StackOverflow makes me rephrase a comment to get past its censorship rules. Who do these people think they are, to deem the comment "What have you tried?" not acceptable. I think I've earned my right to say what I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly make this prettier, more generic, etc., but my first pass would be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
  <table>
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:if test="@border">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('border:', @border, '; ')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@width">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:', @width, '; ')"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>

    <!-- either this or apply-templates -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>

  </table>
</xsl:template>
```